# MySQL Normalization - 1 table with 3 columns or 2 tables with 2 columns?

Tags: database-normalization

I am building a database with a couple of million records, and I've got a question regarding one of the relational tables which will be used to store two searchable reference numbers. I am new to this, so I apologize f this has been asked before.

```
id          digit1      digit2

varchar(9)  varchar(9)  varchar(9)
```

1. Is it better to a) keep 2 separate optional columns in one table or b) two separate tables for digit1 and digit2?
2. What kind of a mysql character type should I use if digit1 always consists of 6 - 9 numbers and digit2 always consists of same 3 letters and 6 numbers? How do I limit the input by a set of such rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

actually, if you're going to store numbers and if you don't want to query by digit1 and digit2 at the same time, it's better to keep them apart in different tables. Otherwise, it's better to keep them in the same table, or you'll have a painful join. It also depends how sparse is your matrix (I mean, if there are too many items in column 2 and just a few in column 3, probably it's better to keep them apart too)

now, what will make a bigger difference here, if you want to store numbers, is to use a numeric field to store the values (instead of varchar), which will be smaller and faster to search and index (and so, to retrieve)